# Why does Windows update on Windows 10 only show a month of history?

Tags: windows

Looking at the Windows Update history for my machine, I can only see updates installed over the past month. I know my machine hasn't been rebuilt since October last year, but the earliest installed update in Windows update is recorded in September this year.

For example, KB4551762 came out since my machine was rebuilt, but there is no evidence it has been applied. As I'm fully up to date with updates I can only assume this has been patched.

Why is the Windows Update history truncated and is there any way to evidence applied patches or see the full history?

Comment: Try using powershell to see what is installed>>>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/check-windows-update-history-using-powershell

Comment: @Moab Powershell has the exact same problem, the command only returns 6 updates. It seems unlikely that only 6 updates have been done in the past year, all within the last month.

Comment: Did you do a disk cleanup and tick windows updates?

Comment: @Moab I haven't knowingly. Unless there is something pushed From IT that does it.

Comment: Major Feature Updates like 2004, which are reinstalls, reset the update history.Minor Feature Updates like 20H2 don't.  When was 2004 installed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding of how to get a list of installed Windows 10 updates, please try the following methods:
**1. Via the Control Panel**

Open **Start menu/Cortana**.

Search for **Control Panel**.

In Control Panel, navigate to **Programs > Programs and Features**.

Click on '**View Installed Updates**' to see the full list of additional updates.

You can also use the search bar and type KB number of an update to find it.

**2. See your update history with Command Prompt and SystemInfo**

Open **Search/Cortana**.

Search for '**cmd**'.

Open a c**ommand prompt with admin privileges**.

Type **systeminfo.exe** and press **Enter**.

Under the **Hotfix(s) section**, you can find the list of Windows updates that you have installed on your device.

**3. Use PowerShell to get a list of installed updates**

Right-click **Start menu icon**

Click on '**Windows PowerShell (Admin)**'.

When the PowerShell prompt opens, type **Get-Hotfix** and press **Enter** to get a list of installed updates and their installation dates.

It is also possible to check if a particular update is installed by using the KB number as an argument. For example, the command **Get-Hotfix KB4551762** will check if the KB4551762 is installed.